# Having trouble showing the forecast data after emptying the previous data

Tags: jquery, api

I am trying to display a 5 day forecast, however every time I empty out the data from the previous forecast, it only shows the data from the last day of the 5 day forecast. I've tried to put the `.empty()` method everywhere, but nothing seems to work.

```
$.ajax({
  url: queryURLThree,
   method: "GET"
 }).then(function (forecastResT) {

  for (var i = 0; i < forecastResT.list.length; i++) {
    if (forecastResT.list[i].dt_txt.indexOf("18:00:00") !== -1) {
      var day = forecastResT.list[i].dt_txt.split(" ")  
      var forecastNameS = $('<div class="col"><p>' + day[0] + '</p>')
      // add icon logos based on their weather conditions

     var imgOne = $("<img>").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + forecastResT.list[i].weather[0].icon + ".png");
     var tempFiveOne = $('<div id = "tempFive">'+ 'Temperature: ' +forecastResT.list[i].main.temp + '<div>');
     var humFiveOne = $('<div id = "humFive"> '+'Humidity: ' + forecastResT.list[i].main.humidity + '<div>');
     $('#fiveDay').empty();
     forecastNameS.append(imgOne);
     forecastNameS.append(tempFiveOne);
     forecastNameS.append(humFiveOne);
     ($('#fiveDay').append(forecastNameS));
  }
}
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over the 5 news days, and use `empty()` each time. This means you'll erase the previous day as soon as you're adding the next one, and only the last one will remains.

Use `empty()` **before** your loop:

```js
$('#fiveDay').empty();
for (var i = 0; i < forecastResT.list.length; i++) {
  if (forecastResT.list[i].dt_txt.indexOf("18:00:00") !== -1) {
    var day = forecastResT.list[i].dt_txt.split(" ")  
    var forecastNameS = $('<div class="col"><p>' + day[0] + '</p>')
    // add icon logos based on their weather conditions

    var imgOne = $("<img>").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + forecastResT.list[i].weather[0].icon + ".png");
    var tempFiveOne = $('<div id = "tempFive">'+ 'Temperature: ' +forecastResT.list[i].main.temp + '<div>');
    var humFiveOne = $('<div id = "humFive"> '+'Humidity: ' + forecastResT.list[i].main.humidity + '<div>');

    forecastNameS.append(imgOne);
    forecastNameS.append(tempFiveOne);
    forecastNameS.append(
    $('#fiveDay').append(forecastNameS);
  }
}
```

Comment: When I put the empty method there, the 5 day forecast shows. However, the data doesn't change. It remains the same after I input different cites.

Comment: Something might be wrong with my loop b/c it will change the data once, but if I search for another a city the data from the previous city remains as the 5 day forecast.